# Wordpress error: Unable to resolve the UBL automatically with the values cooked

Tags: wordpress

I don´t know what happend with this wordpress, i only upload de image and now the site dont save the new pages abd give me that error.

can u give a litght about how resolve this?

Wordpress 4.9.8

[image: UBL Error]

Answer (score 0):

Change your Wordpress theme to default Wordpress theme, then check have error
After that once deactivate Wordpress plugins and again active that